# "Filtrar" registros iguais em uma lista somando seus quantitativos

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lista

```
namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Teste> lstTeste = new List<Teste>
            {
                new Teste {Codigo = 1, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 2, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 1, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 3, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 2, Quantidade = 10}
            };
        }
    }

    public class Teste
    {
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    }
```

Eu quero criar uma nova lista, ou remover os itens repetidos da lista original, porém quero somar os quantitativos.

A "nova" lista ficaria:

```
Codigo = 1, Quantitativo = 20
Codigo = 2, Quantitativo = 20
Codigo = 3, Quantitativo = 10
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilizando LINQ você pode agrupar os itens por código e somar a quantidade em cada grupo. Entretanto, o LINQ só está disponível a partir da versão 3.5 e em alguns casos precisamos trabalhar com versões anteriores, então fiz também uma solução agrupando e somando utilizando um `Dictionary` como estrutura chave/valor para agrupar os itens por código e somar as quantidades diretamente no valor do item no dicionário.

## Com LINQ

```
namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Teste> lstTeste = new List<Teste>
            {
                new Teste {Codigo = 1, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 2, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 1, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 3, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 2, Quantidade = 10}
            };

            List<Teste> lstAgrupado = lstTeste
                .GroupBy(i => i.Codigo)
                .Select(j => new Teste()
                {
                    Codigo = j.First().Codigo,
                    Quantidade = j.Sum(ij => ij.Quantidade)
                })
                .ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Teste
    {
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Sem LINQ

```
namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Teste> lstTeste = new List<Teste>
            {
                new Teste {Codigo = 1, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 2, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 1, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 3, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 2, Quantidade = 10}
            };

            Dictionary<int, Teste> agrupamentoSomado = new Dictionary<int, Teste>();

            foreach (Teste item in lstTeste)
            {
                if (agrupamentoSomado.ContainsKey(item.Codigo))
                {
                    agrupamentoSomado[item.Codigo].Quantidade += item.Quantidade;
                }
                else
                {
                    agrupamentoSomado.Add(item.Codigo, item);
                }
            }

            List<Teste> lstAgrupado = new List<Teste>(agrupamentoSomado.Values);
        }
    }

    public class Teste
    {
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu fiz em três formas diferentes para escolher o que melhor te atende:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using static System.Console;

namespace ConsoleApplication10 {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<Teste> lstTeste = new List<Teste> {
                new Teste {Codigo = 1, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 2, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 1, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 3, Quantidade = 10},
                new Teste {Codigo = 2, Quantidade = 10}
            };

            //Forma declarativa
            WriteLine("Forma declarativa");
            var items = from item in lstTeste
                group item by item.Codigo
                into g
                select new{Codigo = g.Key, Quantidade = g.Sum(item => item.Quantidade)};
            items.ToList().ForEach(item => { WriteLine(
                $"Item: {item.Codigo} Quantidade: {item.Quantidade}"); });

            //forma imperativa
            WriteLine("Forma imperativa");
            var lista = lstTeste.GroupBy(g => g.Codigo).Select(g => new {
                Codigo = g.First().Codigo, Quantidade = g.Sum(g => g.Quantidade) });
            lista.ToList().ForEach(item => { WriteLine(
                $"Item: {item.Codigo} Quantidade: {item.Quantidade}"); });

            //forma com dicionário - Sem LINQ
            WriteLine("Forma com dicionário");
            var dicionario = new Dictionary<int, Teste>();
            foreach (var item in lstTeste) {
                if (dicionario.ContainsKey(item.Codigo)) {
                    dicionario[item.Codigo].Quantidade += item.Quantidade;
                } else {
                    dicionario[item.Codigo] = item;
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in dicionario.Values) {
                WriteLine($"Item: {item.Codigo} Quantidade: {item.Quantidade}");
            }
       }
    }

    public class Teste {
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/sQsSYo). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pLtz83). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Filter.cs).

Answer (score 3):

Uma resposta usando os métodos de extensão do `System.Linq` e retorno com objetos anônimos:

```
var resultado = lstTeste
      .GroupBy(x => x.Codigo)
      .Select(x => new { 
          Quantitativo = x.Sum(y => y.Quantidade), 
          Codigo = x.First().Codigo
      });
```

Veja funcionando aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S1FKzY

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<Teste> SomarIguais(List<Teste> list)
{
    if(list == null) return null;
    List<Teste> resultado = new List<Teste>();
    foreach(Teste t in list)
    {
        bool nenhum = true;
        foreach(Teste t1 in resultado)
        {
            if(t1.Codigo == t.Codigo)
            {
                nenhum = false;
                t1.Quantidade += t.Quantidade;
            }
        }
        if(nenhum) resultado.Add(t);
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Christian, procure explicar um pouco da lógica que você adotou quando postar uma resposta. E se não tiver o LINQ disponível sugiro a utilização de `Dictionary` ;)

Comment: Eu sinceramente nunca tinha usado o Linq. Quanto a lógica pareceu tão "boba" que nem achei necessário

Comment: É uma questão de boa prática, Christian. O que pode ser trivial pra você pode não ser pra outras pessoas. Pra quem fez a pergunta, por exemplo, claramente não é uma questão tão boba.